# Borland Error E2194: Could not find file, qoutes issue in makefile

Tags: batch-file, makefile, c++builder-5

I have some project which built on Borland, below the version.

[image]

I can clean/make/build it inside the IDE

[image]

Till today I was able to make it in cmd:

```
cd C:\repos\gradlecpp\Project\src\AssDelay
T:\Bin\bpr2mak.exe TSAssDelay.bpr
T:\Bin\make.exe -fTSAssDelay.mak
```

After execution of commands abowe, I had `.dll` file.

Today all I did systemwide, is deinstallation of `MSSql Server`, and now I get follow error:

```
C:\repos\gradlecpp\Project\src\AssDelay>T:\Bin\make.exe -fTSAssDelay.mak
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
        T:\Bin\..\BIN\bcc32 -WD -Od -H=T:\Bin\..\lib\vcl50.csm -Hc -Vx -Ve -X- -r- -a8 -b- -k -y -v -vi-   -c -tWM -w-par -I..\DocGoodsCards;"C:\Program Files\B
orland\CBuilder5\Bin\";"D:\My project\tmp\";..\GroupClients;T:\Bin\..\Imports;P:\Tr\;L:\RSD\;"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects\";..\Common;"C:\Progra
m Files\Common Files\System\MAPI\1049\nt\";C:\;T:\Bin\..\include;T:\Bin\..\include\vcl;T:\Bin\..\include\atl;L:\CDBTypeLibrary\;L:\EhLib\;L:\FastReport\;L:\Grap
hics\;L:\ImgEdit\;L:\LGTypeLibrary\;L:\ML\;L:\Rx\;L:\TS\;L:\TSBF\;L:\TSTypeLibrary\;L:\VCLZip\;"L:\DL\" -D_DEBUG;_RTLDLL;NO_STRICT;_ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED;USING
_ATLVCL;_ATL_NO_SECURITY;INC_ATL_HEADERS;USEPACKAGES -n .\TSAssDelay.cpp .\TSAssDelay_ATL.cpp .\TSAssDelay_TLB.cpp .\FmDocAssDelayList.cpp .\DocAssDelayImpl.cpp
 .\FmDocAssDelayItem.cpp .\DmDocAssDelay.cpp .\FmDocAssLimitList.cpp .\DocAssLimitImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssLimitItem.cpp .\DmDocAssLimit.cpp .\FmDocAssDelayFU.cpp .\F
mOrdChngFU.cpp .\DmDocAssIU.cpp .\FmDocAssIUList.cpp .\FmDocAssIUItem.cpp .\FmDocAssIULine.cpp .\DocAssIUImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssIUPercent.cpp .\DmDocAss.cpp .\DocAs
sImpl.cpp .\FmDocAss.cpp
Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
Error E2194: Could not find file 'project\tmp";..\GroupClients;T:\Bin\..\Imports;P:\Tr\;L:\RSD\;C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects";..\Common;C:\Progra
m.cpp'
Error E2194: Could not find file 'Files\Common.cpp'
Error E2194: Could not find file 'Files\System\MAPI\1049\nt";C:\;T:\Bin\..\include;T:\Bin\..\include\vcl;T:\Bin\..\include\atl;L:\CDBTypeLibrary\;L:\EhLib\;L:\F
astReport\;L:\Graphics\;L:\ImgEdit\;L:\LGTypeLibrary\;L:\ML\;L:\Rx\;L:\TS\;L:\TSBF\;L:\TSTypeLibrary\;L:\VCLZip\;L:\DL" -D_DEBUG;_RTLDLL;NO_STRICT;_ATL_APARTMEN
T_THREADED;USING_ATLVCL;_ATL_NO_SECURITY;INC_ATL_HEADERS;USEPACKAGES -n .\TSAssDelay.cpp .\TSAssDelay_ATL.cpp .\TSAssDelay_TLB.cpp .\FmDocAssDelayList.cpp .\Doc
AssDelayImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssDelayItem.cpp .\DmDocAssDelay.cpp .\FmDocAssLimitList.cpp .\DocAssLimitImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssLimitItem.cpp .\DmDocAssLimit.cpp .\FmDocAs
sDelayFU.cpp .\FmOrdChngFU.cpp .\DmDocAssIU.cpp .\FmDocAssIUList.cpp .\FmDocAssIUItem.cpp .\FmDocAssIULine.cpp .\DocAssIUImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssIUPercent.cpp .\DmDo
cAss.cpp .\DocAssImpl.cpp .\FmDocAss.cpp .cpp'
```

So now, I don't have resulting `.dll`.

Same error I have if I create and run make file from IDE using `Project -> Export Makefile...`, `Project -> Execute Makefile`.

Here is the part of Makefile, which supposedly reasons the error:

```
SYSDEFINES = _RTLDLL;NO_STRICT;_ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED;USING_ATLVCL;_ATL_NO_SECURITY;INC_ATL_HEADERS;USEPACKAGES
INCLUDEPATH = ..\DocGoodsCards;"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Bin\";"D:\My project\tmp\";..\GroupClients;$(BCB)\Imports;P:\Tr\;L:\RSD\;"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects\";..\Common;"C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\MAPI\1049\nt\";C:\;$(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl;$(BCB)\include\atl;L:\CDBTypeLibrary\;L:\EhLib\;L:\FastReport\;L:\Graphics\;L:\ImgEdit\;L:\LGTypeLibrary\;L:\ML\;L:\Rx\;L:\TS\;L:\TSBF\;L:\TSTypeLibrary\;L:\VCLZip\;"L:\DL\"
LIBPATH = "C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects\Lib\";L:\Bpl\;..\DocGoodsCards;"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Bin\";"D:\My project\tmp\";"L:\DevExpress\ExpressEditors Library\Lib\";L:\DevExpress\ExpressInplaceEditors\Lib\;L:\DevExpress\ExpressQuantumGrid\Lib\;..\GroupClients;L:\DevExpress\Lib\;$(BCB)\Imports;P:\Tr\;L:\RSD\;"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects\";..\Common;"C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\MAPI\1049\nt\";L:\EhLib\;$(BCB)\Lib;$(BCB)\Lib\Obj;L:\Lib\;L:\ML\;L:\TS\;L:\TSBF\;"L:\DL\"
```

What else, before we had some script as part of automated build system, that fixed makefile:

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %1|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:\"=\."%%"
        rem call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)

echo HERE
```

It is really impossible to understand what is going here... I think it is easier to understand compiled code in hex editor, than MS batch files... What I think is done there, is replacing of quotes. I tried to remove the quotes, but it didn't helps...

Can some one help me to make this project be compiled from cmd?

**UPDATE**

OK, so I get the command produced from `make.exe -fTSAssdelay.mak` and removed all directories paths which contained spaces:

```
@echo off

T:\Bin\bcc32 -WD -Od -H=T:\Bin\..\lib\vcl50.csm -Hc -Vx -Ve -X- -r- -a8 -b- -k -y -v -vi-   -c -tWM -w-par ^
-IL:\TS\;L:\TSBF\ -I..\GroupClients -I..\DocGoodsCards -IT:\Bin\..\Imports -IP:\Tr\ -IL:\RSD\ -I..\Common -IC:\ ^
-IT:\Bin\..\include -IT:\Bin\..\include\vcl -IT:\Bin\..\include\atl -IL:\CDBTypeLibrary\ -IL:\EhLib\ -IL:\FastReport\ ^
-IL:\Graphics\ -IL:\ImgEdit\ -IL:\LGTypeLibrary\ -IL:\ML\ -IL:\Rx\ -IL:\TSTypeLibrary\ -IL:\VCLZip\ -IL:\DL\ ^
-D_DEBUG;_RTLDLL;NO_STRICT;_ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED;USING_ATLVCL;_ATL_NO_SECURITY;INC_ATL_HEADERS;USEPACKAGES -n ^
.\TSAssDelay.cpp .\TSAssDelay_ATL.cpp .\TSAssDelay_TLB.cpp .\FmDocAssDelayList.cpp .\DocAssDelayImpl.cpp ^
.\FmDocAssDelayItem.cpp .\DmDocAssDelay.cpp .\FmDocAssLimitList.cpp .\DocAssLimitImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssLimitItem.cpp ^
.\DmDocAssLimit.cpp .\FmDocAssDelayFU.cpp .\FmOrdChngFU.cpp .\DmDocAssIU.cpp .\FmDocAssIUList.cpp .\FmDocAssIUItem.cpp ^
.\FmDocAssIULine.cpp .\DocAssIUImpl.cpp .\FmDocAssIUPercent.cpp .\DmDocAss.cpp .\DocAssImpl.cpp .\FmDocAss.cpp

rem -I"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects\" -I"C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\MAPI\1049\nt\"
rem -I"C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Bin\" -I"D:\My project\tmp\" ^
```

As you can see, it is also possible to keep them together: `-IL:\TS\;L:\TSBF\`

So now, I get `.obj` files, but I still need to link.

If I remove those paths from makefile, I get:

```
C:\repos\gradlecpp\Project\src\AssDelay>make.exe -fTSAssDelay.mak
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
        C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin\..\BIN\bcc32 -WD -Od -H=C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin\..\lib\vcl50.csm -Hc -Vx -Ve -X- -r- -a8 -b- -k -y -v -vi-   -c -tWM -w-par -I..\DocGoodsCar
ds;..\GroupClients;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin\..\Imports;P:\Tr\;L:\RSD\;..\Common;C:\;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin\..\include;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin\..\include\vcl;C:\PRO
GRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin\..\include\atl;L:\CDBTypeLibrary\;L:\EhLib\;L:\FastReport\;L:\Graphics\;L:\ImgEdit\;L:\LGTypeLibrary\;L:\ML\;L:\Rx\;L:\TS\;L:\TSBF\;L:\TSTypeLibrary\;L:\VCLZip\;"L
:\DL\" -D_DEBUG;_RTLDLL;NO_STRICT;_ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED;USING_ATLVCL;_ATL_NO_SECURITY;INC_ATL_HEADERS;USEPACKAGES -n..\Common\ ..\Common\FmSelDoctype.cpp
Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
Error E2266: No file names given
```

Comment: `Could not find file 'project\tmp";..\GroupClients;T:\Bin\..\Imports;P:\Tr\;L:\RSD\;C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Projects";..\Common;C:\Progra
m.cpp'` 

It's actually looking for a file with such a garbled filename, which of course fails. Why it is now suddenly asked to look for that file I don't know. I think  you did more than uninstall the SQL server?

Comment: And? It is clear that here is problem of quotes, I just need to understand what the problem.

Comment: Maybe this is a "new line issue", where Windows required CRLF and your editor suddenly changed all those to just LF in the makefile?

Comment: This question is likely not suited to the Q&A format due to the fact that there are external factors that the readers can't discern. With that in mind, the problem seems to be with the processing of the parameters and perhaps Borland's support for spaces in paths, i.e. the `project\tmp[...].cpp` that it can't find is split off of `-I[...]D:\My project\tmp`, then `.cpp` is added because it thinks it's a file. (Same with `Files\Common.cpp` from `C:\Program Files\Common Files` etc.)

Comment: Yes, it is clear that it is quotes problem (spaces between quotes), so can you read the batch code that supposed to fix it?

Comment: Good idea,  Joakim L. Christiansen... but there is no new lines in these places in makefile... can you understand what going in batch file?

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova `I think it is easier to understand compiled code in hex editor, than MS batch files` I totally agree! That syntax hurts my brain. Good that you found a solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Solutions

#### Removing paths

OK, so one solution is to remove all representation of paths with space. If you have some include header or lib directory with space in it's path, you need to do one of the follow:

1. Rename the folder
2. Make hard link (if it is possible in Windows)
3. Mount folder to virual drive

Using perl, it can be something like:

```
$_ = $makefile_content
s/"[^"]*";?//
```

#### Patch the template

Other solution, is use makefile template, where you will substitute `BCC32` definition in `MAKE SECTION` with:

```
!if !$d(BCC32)
BCC32 = bcc32ide
!endif
```

The original block is:

```
!if !$d(BCC32)
BCC32 = bcc32
!endif
```

It seems that `bcc32ide.exe` respects paths, which includes spaces.

The original template is `default.bmk` placed in Borland's bin folder, so copy the file, substitute `BCC32` definition, lets the new name will be `patched.bmk`. Than call `bpr2mak.exe` with modified template. At the finish call `make.exe`:

```
> bpr2mak.exe project.bpr -tpatched.bmk
> make.exe -fproject.mak
```